# Why is this datetime parse failing for "02/13/2013"?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse the string "02/13/2013" into a datetime and it doesn't work. (it doesn't set dt to the value of dtResult because the tryprase didn't pass.

Here is what I am doing:

```
DateTime dtResult;

var dt = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtResult))
{
    dt = dtResult;
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it throw an exception, does it null-fill the output value, does it do nothing? What do you think the issue is?

Comment: what error do you get if you don't use `try`? It might be instructive...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cause month 13 do not exist.

You should put your format as "MM/dd/yyyy".

Comment: ah, i swapped it around!

Answer (score 3):

Because 13. month doesn't exist. From *[`wikipedia`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month)*;

> The Gregorian calendar, like the Julian calendar before it, has twelve
>   months.

Try with `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

```
DateTime dtResult;
var dt = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("02/13/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtResult))
{
    dt = dtResult;
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/9N21A3)..